# heroku heroku labs:enable user-env-compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cdn, precompile

I'm trying to precompile and push my files to a cdn...per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31

However, when I run this

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a <<my app>>
```

I get the following error

```
-----> Enabling user-env-compile for sleepy-castle-9766... failed
 !    Application error
```

Logs:

```
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (38.3ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (9.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (67.5ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (9.5ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (38.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (10.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (94.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299446+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (15.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (9.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (11.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (28.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (13.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (16.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_login.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (12.3ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1607.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1613ms (Views: 769.4ms | ActiveRecord: 843.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (10.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (43.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (477.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (233.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (45.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (41.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (38.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.299894+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (40.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:48.300656+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:41:49.264569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/img/greenlogo.png host=www.imissyou.com fwd="76.98.253.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-15T04:41:49.289944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/img/homepagetopheader.png host=www.imissyou.com fwd="76.98.253.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-15T04:42:42.366874+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 95.211.87.85 at 2013-04-15 04:42:42 +0000
2013-04-15T04:42:43.722607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=www.imissyou.com fwd="95.211.87.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1355ms status=200 bytes=80024
2013-04-15T04:42:44.743673+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (8.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.743673+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (40.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.743673+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-04-15T04:42:44.743673+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (48.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.743673+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (55.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (39.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (8.5ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (24.3ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (8.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.3ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (39.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (13.6ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (29.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (11.5ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (9.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744453+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (382.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (44.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (268.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (5.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (8.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (63.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (38.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (16.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (9.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.3ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.8ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (8.1ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (273.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744698+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (42.9ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1333.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/_login.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745438+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745438+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1339ms (Views: 750.7ms | ActiveRecord: 587.7ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (6.4ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (11.0ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.744943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (7.2ms)
2013-04-15T04:42:44.745185+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/_vote.html.erb (37.0ms)
```

Comment: can you show your heroku logs

Comment: just running heroku logs?  when i do that, no errors show....

Comment: plz refer this link http://blog.genuitytech.com/2012/01/31/heroku-labs-and-user-env-compile/  it will helpful for you

Comment: that doesn't help at all...I'm showing you that when I run the heroku labs command, I get the error above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the documentation on the asset_sync github page that says when you run command:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile --app <appname>
```

In order for it to work.

Heroku also has AssetSync https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31#configuration documentation

It's so nice to only be compiling assets once now

This worked for me as well when I wanted to get a direct deploy to Heroku. I use the **i18n-js** https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js gem which requires `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` in `application.rb.`

So, this command allowed me to not have to precompile assets at all before deployment. I really help Heroku keeps this around.

Also we called heroku `labs:enable user-env-compile -a <appname>`, not user_env_compile.

**Edited:** 
For working this issue, just update your `heroku toolbelt`, please refer below mentioned link
https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/10/15/upgrading-to-the-heroku-toolbelt

Comment: Asset sync is already installed, and heroku labs:enable... is giving the error above (even with dashes).  Are you saying that I should install i18n-js too?

Comment: Turns out I need to update my heroku toolbelt...it was an old version of heroku

Comment: For upgrade heroku toolbelt try this link <https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/10/15/upgrading-to-the-heroku-toolbelt>

Comment: sure...just change the answer so that it's the right one :)  I didn't end up using i18n-js, had to update heroku to the new toolbelt